# Html Agility Pack, SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

This code works

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        html = client.DownloadString("http://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter?ref_=nv_mv_mpm_8");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        MessageBox.Show(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='main']/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a").InnerText);
```

Html codes here:

```
<a href="/title/tt4972582/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=2240084082&amp;pf_rd_r=1QW31NGD6JSE46F79CKQ&amp;pf_rd_s=center-1&amp;pf_rd_t=15506&amp;pf_rd_i=moviemeter&amp;ref_=chtmvm_tt_1" title="M. Night Shyamalan (dir.), James McAvoy, Anya Taylor-Joy">Split</a>
```

MessageBox shows the text which is "Split". But look this Html codes:

```
<div class="summary_text" itemprop="description">
                Three girls are kidnapped by a man with a diagnosed 23 distinct personalities, and must try and escape before the apparent emergence of a frightful new 24th.
        </div>
```

I want MessageBox to show the text which starts with "Three girls are kidn..." so i wrote this code:

```
        WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
        client2.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc2.LoadHtml(client2.DownloadString("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4972582/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2240084082&pf_rd_r=1QW31NGD6JSE46F79CKQ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=moviemeter&ref_=chtmvm_tt_1"));
        MessageBox.Show(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='title - overview - widget']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]").InnerText);
```

When i start this code,an unhandled exception of type "System.NullReferenceException" occurred

Xpaths are true, i've checked a hundred times so what should i do?

Comment: Why don't you use a specific xpath for that element rather than go through another? Since that xpath doesn't match the element you want at least at the moment. The description is not inside that div.

Comment: How can i reach this description? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4972582/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2240084082&pf_rd_r=1QW31NGD6JSE46F79CKQ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=moviemeter&ref_=chtmvm_tt_1");
        var desNodeText = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "summary_text").InnerText;
```

Comment: or as xpath: `//div[@class='summary_text']`